# Como abrir um link em um navegador que foi clicado em um WebView no Android

Tags: android, android-webview

Pessoal quero abrir um link que vai ser clicado no WebView, quero que esse abra no navegador. Tenho aqui o código:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains(url)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Porém na primeira vez que é clicado abre no próprio aplicativo!

Answer (score -1):

Você tem que criar um `Intent` para abrir o link no navegador.

1 - Crie uma `String` com o sua URL
2 - Crie um objeto `Intent` passando como argumento `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`, isso fará com que o android busque apps no dispositivo que consiga abrir essa URL (o navegador é um).
 
3 - Passe sua string contendo sua URL como parâmetro do metoto `setData(url)` da classe Intent (use o metodo Uri.parse(sua_string_url) para converter a string para um URI).
4 - Chame o metodo `startActivity(intent)` passando o `intent` propriamente configurado com os passos anteriores.

```
String url = "http://www.yourlink.com"; // Cria a string - URL
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); // Cria o Intent
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)); // Passa a string para url e passa como um argumento do metodo setData(url)
startActivity(intent); //chama o metodo startActivity(intent) passando o intent e o navegador é aberto aqui.
```

Comment: Olá @Carlos. Desenvolva mais a sua resposta. Por exemplo, explique o que faz.

Comment: @JoãoMartins, Tá ok assim? :)